# c# application use GSM Modem(to send sms) with serialport. Hebrew not work when message receive

Tags: c#, encoding, sms

I have a problem sending Hebrew messages, tried few encoding in few ways.

`SMSPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` - and some other encoding not work.
**Smsport is serialPort object

```
public void SendSMS(string CellNumber, string SMSMessage){   
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine); 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);   
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CSCS=GSM" + Environment.NewLine);    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);    
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" + (char)34 + CellNumber
            + (char)34 + Environment.NewLine);    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);   
            SMSPort.WriteLine(SMSMessage + (char)26);   
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);          
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a library that uses PDU encoding.

[GSMcomm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/GSMComm_v1.21.exe) will be a good and recommended example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16")`

if that doesn't work try one of the following:

iso-8859-8
OR 
windows-1255

it is recommended to **clean** the project between each try :)

Comment: did you clean it each time?

Comment: and did you noticed i wrote utf-16 and NOT utf-8?

Comment: did all u mention, still same problem.